# Putting API key and secret in my Firefox addon

Tags: api, firefox-addon, secret-key

I am developing a Firefox addon and I want to integrate with some third party service that uses oauth for authentication. I therefore have an API key and secret that I need to use to communicate with their API. If I were to include my API key and secret in the source code of the addon, would people (users of the addon, etc) be able to figure the key and secret out? Is there some mechanism in the SDK to store secrets in addons?

The alternative, that I used in my proof of concept, is that I ask the user to generate a key and secret and enter those into the settings. This works, but isn't very user friendly.

Edit:

To clarify, in reaction to a comment, I am not looking for keeping the secrets out of the source code, I am looking for a way to use my own secrets in my addon and keeping them secret to the public. So they would be shipped to everyone using my addon.

Comment: You might find this below topic useful [Strategy for keeping secret info such as API keys out of source control?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control)

Comment: @O-mkar thanks for your answer. My problem however is not with source-control, but with production code. Firefox add-ons are written in Javascript+HTML+CSS, so my API keys would be in the working production code (that is to some extent inspectable by users)

Comment: if you found it useful please rate my comment up :)

Comment: @O-mkar As I said "My problem however is not with source-control" :)

Comment: This is also a problem I faced. One solution I used was to set up a website. I would post to it some generated key, then on the website it checks if the key was properly made. That key works only once. If the site finds the key was properly made, it returns the key. I thought it was a hassle so just dropped my key in my addons. I know I should probably not continue that.

Comment: @Noitidart I also considered running my own website in between, but not in the way you suggest. That sounds interesting, but as you say very cumbersome on my own part. In that case finding some way to automate the entering of complicated looking API keys (to 'normal' users) is probably more fruitful. Also I'd like to thank you for your open-sourced (or at least accessible) addons on github. Coincidence has it that in the past few days I have been looking at them. (Assuming you have the same username on github ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to include my API key and secret in the source code of the addon, would people (users of the addon, etc) be able to figure the key and secret out? Is there some mechanism in the SDK to store secrets in addons?

You're asking whether it's possible to make data inaccessible to a user who has full control over the computer but make it accessible to software running on the very same computer over which the user has full control.

No.

> The alternative, that I used in my proof of concept, is that I ask the user to generate a key and secret and enter those into the settings. This works, but isn't very user friendly.

Then automate the process to make it more user-friendly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree on your first point to a certain extent, but it is not this black and white. Compiled applications can contain secrets that a user, even with 'full control' cannot access. However, as you say, the nature of Firefox (addons' source being open to users) would indeed make it impossible to keep secrets from the user.

As for your second suggestion I will try to do this. Users would have to be logged into the service I am connecting with, but I could automate grabbing the keys from the page that shows them with some type of content script.

Comment: I will wait a while before I give you the answer

Comment: From an information-theoretical and computer-security point of view it is as black and white as I say. You say that people - I quote -  "*cannot access*" it, that's untrue. It may be *difficult* to do so, as in require a little more than trivial effort, but that does not make it impossible. An example would be the Blu-Ray decryption keys. They have been extracted from compiled and obfuscated software players via memory dumps and debuggers.

Comment: Yes you are right. In the same sense you could say that throwing a rock at the moon is just 'difficult'. If you didn't make it you just didn't throw hard enough. Which in a way is true, it is just dependent on your definition of 'throwing' and 'thrower'. In the case of my addon maybe I would've found a compiled 'secret' secretive enough, but all taken into account it is probably best to have people generate their own API keys and secrets and somehow automate entering them into my addon's storage. That way there are no secrets to protect.

Comment: You did not weaken your requirements. You only asked whether "*would people be able to*". If you want more precise answer in the field of computer security you need to state a more precise threat model, which includes the capabilities of a potential attacker and what you want to defend against and at which point you give up. And unlike getting a rock to the moon extracting constants from compiled code is a much easier task, somewhere between minutes and days , assuming an expert in the field of reverse-engineering. So your rock-to-moon analogy is a massive exaggeration regarding difficulty.